# Android MediaPlayer freezes after seeking a new video position

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, buffering

I load a .mp4 on a VideoView, all things go fine until I drag the seekbar point to a new position, so the MediaPlayer starts to buffering and then the app freezes (not crash, just freeze) with an error message:

**"Can't play video"**

This is the code:

```
try {
        // Start the MediaController
        controller.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("video"));
        videoView.setMediaController(controller);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

No errors if I seek an already-buffered position. **Only with no-buffered positions.**

Error log:

```
Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x5c149090, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayer(17339): error (1, -110)
E/MediaPlayer(17339): Error (1,-110)
D/VideoView(17339): Error: 1,-110
```

Comment: did you find the reason for this? how did you fix this?

Comment: @WildChild i m also facing same issue ? how u resolved ?